# which is the best .net library for google maps api?

Tags: .net, google-maps

I need an up to date and easy to use .net wrapper for google maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Googlemap Control](http://www.codeplex.com/googlemap)
Wraps Google Maps API as ASP.NET custom control.
Offers extremely easy and fast way of adding Google Maps API support on your ASP.NET pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Google Maps in your application, then it is most likely that you are going to have to get down-and-dirty with their [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html), which uses JavaScript. It's not all bad though, the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html) is pretty comprehensive and there's an active [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API) as well.

If you really want an ASP.Net server control for a mapping solution, then you could alternatively try [Microsoft's offering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788749.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

.NET wrapper libraries for the Google Maps API (API wrapper, but NOT controls for displaying maps):

1. [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)
2. [google-maps](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61531795