# .NET Library for Google Maps API support

Tags: .net, google-maps, wrapper

I'm looking for a .NET library or wrapper for Google Maps, that contains all the types of responses as C# classes.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Wellington&sensor=false";

//Utility functions would be ideal                  
string jsonResponse = GoogleMaps.GetJson(url);
string jsonResponse = GoogleMaps.GeocodeAddress("Wellington");
```

I would like to be able to use the results like:

```
GeocodeResponse r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeocodeResponse>(jsonResponse);    //I am using Json.NET

if(r.status.Equals("OK"))
{
    DoSomethingWith(r.result.formatted_address);    //intellisense documentation for all the bits in the result would be great
}
```

Does such a thing exist?

This is sort of like these questions:

- [which is the best .net library for google maps api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333635/which-is-the-best-net-library-for-google-maps-api)
- [Best .NET Wrapper for Google Maps or Yahoo Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070/best-net-wrapper-for-google-maps-or-yahoo-maps)

However the answers there are not what I am meaning, I'm not looking for a drag and drop map control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This API is still in development but may provide you with what you are looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-net/

Comment: `gmaps-api-net` (now on GitHub) is outdated

Answer (score 3):

.NET wrapper libraries for the Google Maps API :

1. [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)
2. [google-maps](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps)

[gmaps-api-net](https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net) is outdated (at this time of answering) - the last update for the Directions API was made in 2016.

Usage example for [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi):

```
using GoogleApi.Entities.Common;
using GoogleApi.Entities.Maps.Directions.Request;
using GoogleApi.Entities.Maps.Directions.Response;

public void GetRoute()
{
    DirectionsRequest request = new DirectionsRequest();    

    request.Key = "AIzaSyAJgBs8LYok3rt15rZUg4aUxYIAYyFzNcw";

    request.Origin = new Location("Brasov");
    request.Destination = new Location("Merghindeal");

    var response = GoogleApi.GoogleMaps.Directions.Query(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().DurationInTraffic);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().Distance);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().Steps);
}
```